# Objective-C on Linux Compile Error

Tags: objective-c, linux, ubuntu, gnustep

There seem to be quite a few tutorials on how to do this, each slightly different. I'm hoping someone can recognize the error messages I'm getting and point me in the right direction.

My code, h.m is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
 NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 NSLog (@"hello world");
 [pool drain];
 return 0;
}
```

Before I compile, I enter in the console:

```
. /usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh
```

I try to compile with:

```
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lgnustep-base h.m -o hello
```

and get:

```
/tmp/ccgLOnpY.o: In function `main':
/home/ge/objective-c/h.m:4: undefined reference to `objc_get_class'
/home/ge/objective-c/h.m:4: undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
/home/ge/objective-c/h.m:4: undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
/home/ge/objective-c/h.m:5: undefined reference to `NSLog'
/home/ge/objective-c/h.m:6: undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
/tmp/ccgLOnpY.o: In function `__objc_gnu_init':
/home/ge/objective-c/h.m:8: undefined reference to `__objc_exec_class'
/tmp/ccgLOnpY.o:(.data.rel+0x0): undefined reference to `__objc_class_name_NSConstantString'
/tmp/ccgLOnpY.o:(.data.rel+0x8): undefined reference to `__objc_class_name_NSAutoreleasePool'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

TIA

Comment: Why don't you build with gnustep-make using GNUmakefile? Here's how to write one http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/index.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The reason for the linking error is most likely due to the behaviour of linker to link the libraries only after seeing the symbols in compilation prior to linking the library. As `h.m` appears after `-lgnustep-base` the library is not linked as the symbols in library are not yet encountered. You can either instruct the linker to link the libraries even if the symbols are not encountered using `-Wl,--no-as-needed` linker option as

```
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgnustep-base  h.m -o hello
```

Or better yet just move the source to the beginning of the compilation command as

```
gcc h.m  `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lgnustep-base -o hello
```

The observed linker behaviour is to discourage looking up & linking symbols of library which may not be needed but are linked in the compilation anyway, thus the second option would be recommended way of doing rather than added the `-Wl, --no-as-needed` linker option.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 12):

You'll need to link to libobjc. The fix is pretty simple; just compile with:

```
gcc h.m `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lobjc -lgnustep-base -o hello
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. Using your commandline, I still get the same exact error.

Answer (score 5):

You need to also specify the link flags:

```bsh
gcc h.m `gnustep-config --objc-flags` `gnustep-config --objc-libs` \
-lobjc -lgnustep-base -o hello
```

Answer (score 2):

This method seem good:

```
gcc h.m  `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lgnustep-base -o hello
```